# How to find streamlines normal to magnetic field lines in 2D problem (rz plane of axisymmetric system)?

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I have function $\psi(r,z)$ found from solution of a Grad-Shafranov equation [PDE in 2D]. Magnetic field is expressed through $\psi$ as follows 
$$
\vec{B}(r, z) = 
\left\{
    -\frac{1}{r}\partial_{z}\psi, 0, \frac{1}{r}\partial_{r}\psi
\right\}
.
$$
But I also need a function $\chi(r,z)$ such that its gradient is everywhere perpenticular to the gradient of $\psi$. Same magnetic field is expressed through $\chi$ by 
$$
    \vec{B}(r, z) = G(\psi, \chi) \left\{
    \partial_{r}\chi, 0, \partial_{z}\chi
\right\}
$$
where $G(\psi, \chi)$ is a function also to be found [it is defined upto arbitrary function of $\chi$].

It is easy to draw stream lines of both $\psi(r,z)=$const and $\chi(r,z)=$const using StreamPlot from Wolfram Mathematica by feeding it with vector fields 
$$\left\{
    -\partial_{z}\psi, \partial_{r}\psi \right\}
$$ 
and 
$$
\left\{
    \partial_{r}\psi, \partial_{z}\psi 
\right\}
$$ 
but I need to compute the function $\chi(r,z)$ itself.  Any idea will be apprecieted. I have found one method but it involves integration of a differential equation
$$
\frac{dz}{dr} = \frac{\partial_{z}\psi}{\partial_{r}\psi}
$$
for a set of initial points and subsequent interpolation on a 2D mesh.

Is there a more efficient way to compute $\chi(r,z)$?

Note: Function $G$ can be computed as 
$$
    G(\psi,\chi) = \exp\left(
        -4\pi
        \int_{0}^{\psi} \frac{d{\psi'}}{B^{2}(\psi',\chi)}\,\frac{dp(\psi')}{d\psi'}
    \right)
,
$$
where $p(\psi)$ is a known pressure profile.